# $|x|=|y|=|z|=1$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=-xyz$, are there infinite many values to $|x+y+z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I was playing around with complex numbers and I tried this.

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be complex numbers with the properties
$$|x|=|y|=|z|=1,$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=-xyz.$$

The question is how many values the following expression can take?
$$|x+y+z|.$$
It is easy to see that
$$|x+y+z|≤3,$$

but I found only $2$ solutions
if $x=z=-y$ then $|x+y+z| =1$,
and
$$x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i ,\; y=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i,\;  z=1 $$
then $|x+y+z|=2$.

I believe there are infinitely many values but I couldn't find any other than these two solution.

I want a prove that there are infinite many values for $|x+y+z|$.

If there are finite values for$|x+y+z|$ then how many values? and also what is the greatest value of$|x+y+z|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$$

$$-4xyz=(x+y+z)((x+y+z)^2-3(xy+yz+zx))$$

from $xy+yz+zx$ take $xyz$ common
so you get
$$-4xyz=(x+y+z)((x+y+z)^2-3xyz(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}))$$

Now $|x|=1$ so we have $x \bar{x}=1$ so $\frac{1}{x}=\bar{x}$

So,
$$-4xyz=(x+y+z)((x+y+z)^2-3xyz(\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}))$$
$$-4xyz=(x+y+z)((x+y+z)^2-3xyz(\overline{x+y+z}))$$

$$-4xyz=(x+y+z)^3-3xyz(|x+y+z|^2)$$

$$xyz( 3|x+y+z|^2-4)=(x+y+z)^3$$

Taking modulus both sides

$$|3|x+y+z|^2-4|=|x+y+z|^3$$

substitute $|x+y+z|=t$
$$|3t^2-4|=t^3$$

Now you can solve for t. There will definitely be finite number of t

Comment: but the equation has only 1 solution for t which is 1 , but I fount that there is another solution which is 2.

Comment: @Ahmed 2 is also a solution of this equation $|3*4-4|=2^3$. You can plot the graph for clarity

Comment: sorry I made an error while calculating , but this implies that these 2 are the only solutions

Answer (score 4):

I think there are only finitely many possible values.

The equation
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=-xyz\qquad(*)$$
is homogeneous, so everything in sight is unaffected by the transformation $$(x,y,z)\mapsto (\lambda x,\lambda y, \lambda z),$$ where $|\lambda|=1$. So without loss of generality we can assume that $z=-1$ (use $\lambda=-1/z$), when $(*)$ reads
$$
x^3+y^3=1+xy.\qquad(**)
$$
As $x$ and $y$ are on the unit circle, so are $x^3,y^3,1$ and $xy$. Therefore the arguments of both sides of $(**)$ are the averages of the arguments of the terms. In other words.
$$
\frac12(3\arg x+3\arg y)\equiv \frac12(\arg x+\arg y)\pmod{2\pi}.
$$
Moving all the terms to the left hand side this can be rewritten to give
$\arg x+\arg y\equiv0\pmod{2\pi}.$ In other words, $x$ and $y$ must have opposite arguments. As they are on the unit circle, it follows that
$$y=\overline{x}=\frac1x.$$
Plugging this into the equation $(**)$ yields
$$x^3+\frac1{x^3}=2.\qquad(***)$$
This is a degree six equation, so there are at most six solutions for $x$. Hence at most six possible values for $|x+y+z|$. Actually the solutions of $(***)$ are the third roots of unity, so we only get the two possible values for $|x+y+z|$ that you found yourself.

Comment: Hmm. I need to  leave the caveat that the average of two arguments is two-valued. I don't think it affects the conclusion, but that needs to be checked. Gotta commute next, so I am leaving this as it is. Anyone is welcome to post a fixed version.

Comment: Ok. dxiv was more careful :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks ;-) I think all it changes is a $\,\pm 2\,$ in $\,(***)\,$, which doesn't affect the conclusion.

Comment: thank you very much for your fascinating proof

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\;$ let $\,u=\dfrac{x}{z}\,$, $\,v=\dfrac{y}{z}\,$ where $\,z \ne 0\,$ since $\,|z|=1\,$, then the system can be written as:

$$
\begin{align}
|u|=|v|=1
\\ u^3 + v^3 + 1 + uv = 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Taking the conjugate of $\,(1)\,$, and using that $\,\overline u = \dfrac{|u|^2}{u} = \dfrac{1}{u}\,$, $\,\overline v = \dfrac{1}{v}\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\overline u^3 + \overline v^3 + 1 + \overline u \overline v = 0
\\ u^3 + v^3 + u^3v^3 +u^2 v^2 = 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Subtracting $\,(2)-(1)\,$:

$$
u^3v^3 + u^2v^2 - uv - 1 = 0
$$

It follows that $\,uv = t\,$ is a root of $\,t^3+t^2-t-1=0\,$, so $\,t = \pm 1 \iff u = \pm \dfrac{1}{v} = \overline v\,$.

Substituting back in $\,(1)\,$:

$$
\pm \overline v^3 + v^3 + 1 \pm \overline v v = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; v^6 + v^3 \pm v^3 \pm 1 = 0 \tag{3}
$$

What's left is to solve $\,(3)\,$ for $\,v\,$, then reverse the substitutions back to $\,u, x, y, z\,$. There will be infinitely many solutions $\,(x,y,z)\,$, but finitely many values of $\,|x+y+z|\,$ among those.

Comment: so if |x+y+z| have finite values then how many ? and also what is the greatest value for |x+y+z|

Comment: @Ahmed If you work out the last steps outlined at the end of my answer, equation $(3)$ reduces to $v^3 = \pm 1$, so $u = \bar v = \pm v^2$. Substituting back in $(1)$ verifies that only the "$-$" sign works, and the general solution is $(x, \omega x, \omega^2 x)$ with $|x|=1$ and $\omega$ a cube root of $-1$. Then $\,|x+y+z|$ $=|x| \cdot |1+\omega+\omega^2|\,$ $=|1+\omega+\omega^2|\,$ which is $1$ if $\omega=-1$, or $2$ if $\omega$ is a complex cube root of $-1$.